# How to dynamically align FullCalendar event title in Typescript with Next JS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, fullcalendar, tailwind-css, clsx

This is what I have for now, it notable does not work, and I am really not sure how to tackle this at the moment. Basically I want it so when the user presses '8:00 AM' on the modal it aligns the text to the left and vice versa for '8:30 AM.' I am very inexperienced with dynamic styles and would love to get some insight on this

```
"use client";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin, {
  Draggable,
  DropArg,
} from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, ExclamationTriangleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { EventSourceInput } from "@fullcalendar/core/index.js";
import clsx from "clsx";

interface Event {
  title: string;
  start: Date | string;
  allDay: boolean;
  id: number;
  alignClass: string;
}

export default function Home() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([
    { title: "Employee 1", id: "1", alignClass: "align-left" },
    { title: "Employee 2", id: "2", alignClass: "align-left" },
    { title: "Employee 3", id: "3", alignClass: "align-left" },
    { title: "Employee 4", id: "4", alignClass: "align-left" },
    { title: "Employee 5", id: "5", alignClass: "align-left" },
  ]);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState<Event[]>([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal] = useState(false);
  const [showAlignModal, setShowAlignModal] = useState(false);
  const [idToAlign, setIdToAlign] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [idToDelete, setIdToDelete] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = useState<Event>({
    title: "",
    start: "",
    allDay: false,
    id: 0,
    alignClass: "align-left",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let draggableEl = document.getElementById("draggable-el");
    if (draggableEl) {
      new Draggable(draggableEl, {
        itemSelector: ".fc-event",
        eventData: function (eventEl) {
          let title = eventEl.getAttribute("title");
          let id = eventEl.getAttribute("data");
          let start = eventEl.getAttribute("start");
          return { title, id, start };
        },
      });
    }
  }, []);

  function handleDateClick(arg: { date: Date; allDay: boolean }) {
    setNewEvent({
      ...newEvent,
      start: arg.date,
      allDay: arg.allDay,
      id: new Date().getTime(),
    });
    setShowModal(true);
  }

  function addEvent(data: DropArg) {
    const event = {
      ...newEvent,
      start: data.date.toISOString(),
      title: data.draggedEl.innerText,
      allDay: data.allDay,
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      alignClass: "align-left", // Default alignment when dragged
    };
    setAllEvents([...allEvents, event]);
  }

  function handleEditModal(data: { event: { id: string } }) {
    setIdToAlign(Number(data.event.id));
    setShowAlignModal(true);
  }

  function handleDelete() {
    setAllEvents(
      allEvents.filter((event) => Number(event.id) !== Number(idToDelete))
    );
    setShowDeleteModal(false);
    setIdToDelete(null);
  }

  function alignEvent(alignClass: string) {
    
    setAllEvents((prevEvents) =>
      prevEvents.map((event) =>
        Number(event.id) === Number(idToAlign)
          ? { ...event, alignClass: alignClass }
          : event
      )
    );
    setShowAlignModal(false);
    setIdToAlign(null);
  }

  function handleCloseModal() {
    setShowModal(false);
    setNewEvent({
      title: "",
      start: "",
      allDay: false,
      id: 0,
      alignClass: "",
    });
    setShowDeleteModal(false);
    setIdToDelete(null);
  }

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setNewEvent({
      ...newEvent,
      title: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setAllEvents([...allEvents, newEvent]);
    setShowModal(false);
    setNewEvent({
      title: "",
      start: "",
      allDay: false,
      id: 0,
      alignClass: "align-left",
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex justify-between mb-12 border-b border-violet-100 p-4">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl text-gray-700">Calendar</h1>
      </nav>
      <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-10">
          <div className="col-span-8">
            <FullCalendar
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
              headerToolbar={{
                left: "prev,next today",
                center: "title",
                right: "resourceTimelineWeek, dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek",
              }}
              hiddenDays={[0]}
              events={allEvents as EventSourceInput}
              nowIndicator={true}
              editable={true}
              droppable={true}
              selectable={true}
              selectMirror={true}
              dateClick={handleDateClick}
              drop={(data) => addEvent(data)}
              eventClick={(data) => handleEditModal(data)}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="draggable-el"
            className="ml-8 w-full border-2 p-2 rounded-md mt-16 lg:h-1/2 bg-violet-50"
          >
            <h1 className="font-bold text-lg text-center">Drag Event</h1>
            {events.map((event) => (
              <div
                className={clsx(
                  "fc-event border-2 p-1 m-2 w-full rounded-md ml-auto bg-white",
                  {
                    "text-right": event.alignClass === "align-right",
                    "text-left": event.alignClass === "align-left",
                  }
                )}
                title={event.title}
                key={event.id}
              >
                {event.title}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <Transition.Root show={showAlignModal} as={Fragment}>
          <Dialog
            as="div"
            className="relative z-10"
            onClose={setShowAlignModal}
          >
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
            </Transition.Child>

            <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
              <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                <Transition.Child
                  as={Fragment}
                  enter="ease-out duration-300"
                  enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                  enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                  leave="ease-in duration-200"
                  leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                  leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                >
                  <Dialog.Panel
                    className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg
                   bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg"
                  >
                    <div className="bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                      <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                        <div
                          className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 flex-shrink-0 items-center 
                      justify-center rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10"
                        >
                          <ExclamationTriangleIcon
                            className="h-6 w-6 text-red-600"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                          <Dialog.Title
                            as="h3"
                            className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                          >
                            Change Event
                          </Dialog.Title>
                          <div className="mt-2">
                            <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                              What time will this person start?
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:px-6">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-4 inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white 
    shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 sm:ml-0 sm:w-auto"
                        onClick={() => alignEvent("align-left")}
                      >
                        8:00 AM
                      </button>

                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-8 inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white 
    shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 sm:ml-2 sm:w-auto"
                        onClick={() => alignEvent("align-right")}
                      >
                        8:30 AM
                      </button>

                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 
    shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:ml-10 sm:w-auto"
                        onClick={handleCloseModal}
                      >
                        Cancel
                      </button>

                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-4 inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-red-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white 
    shadow-sm hover:bg-red-500"
                        onClick={handleDelete}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </Dialog.Panel>
                </Transition.Child>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>

        <Transition.Root show={showModal} as={Fragment}>
          <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={setShowModal}>
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
            </Transition.Child>

            <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
              <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                <Transition.Child
                  as={Fragment}
                  enter="ease-out duration-300"
                  enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                  enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                  leave="ease-in duration-200"
                  leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                  leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                >
                  <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg sm:p-6">
                    <div>
                      <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-green-100">
                        <CheckIcon
                          className="h-6 w-6 text-green-600"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-5">
                        <Dialog.Title
                          as="h3"
                          className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                        >
                          Add Event
                        </Dialog.Title>
                        <form action="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                          <div className="mt-2">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="title"
                              className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 
                            shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 
                            focus:ring-2 
                            focus:ring-inset focus:ring-violet-600 
                            sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                              value={newEvent.title}
                              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                              placeholder="Title"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-6 sm:grid sm:grid-flow-row-dense sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-3">
                            <button
                              type="submit"
                              className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-violet-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-violet-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-violet-600 sm:col-start-2 disabled:opacity-25"
                              disabled={newEvent.title === ""}
                            >
                              Create
                            </button>
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:col-start-1 sm:mt-0"
                              onClick={handleCloseModal}
                            >
                              Cancel
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Dialog.Panel>
                </Transition.Child>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried using clsx, but it doesn't work. I think this is honestly not possible.

```
className={clsx(
                  "fc-event border-2 p-1 m-2 w-full rounded-md ml-auto bg-white",
                  {
                    "text-right": event.alignClass === "align-right",
                    "text-left": event.alignClass === "align-left",
                  }
                )}
                title={event.title}
                key={event.id}
              >
```